# GetIterator() and the iterator pattern

Tags: c#, iterator, ienumerable, ienumerator

I'm trying to implement the Iterator pattern.
Basically, from what I understand, it makes a class "foreachble" and makes the code more secure by not revealing the exact collection type to the user.

I have been experimenting a bit and I found out that if I implement
IEnumerator GetEnumerator() in my class, I get the desired result ... seemingly sparing the headache of messing around with realizing interfaces.

Here is a glimpse to what I mean:

```
public class ListUserLoggedIn
{
    /*
        stuff
    */
    
    public List<UserLoggedIn> UserList { get; set; }

    public IEnumerator<UserLoggedIn> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (UserLoggedIn user in this.UserList)
        {
            yield return user;
        }
    }

    public void traverse()
    {
        foreach (var item in ListUserLoggedIn.Instance)
        {
            Console.Write(item.Id);
        }
    }
}
```

I guess my question is, is this a valid example of Iterator?
If yes, why is this working, and what can I do to make the iterator return only a part or an anonymous object via "var".
If not, what is the correct way ...

Comment: your code looks OK, doesn't it work?

Comment: it works... but why?
i thought a design pattern should have a bit more meat to it..

Comment: Design patterns are just approaches to a certain design issue. Sometimes the issue is resolved with minor changes like this, or a singleton.

Comment: The "why" is built-in in the framework. A design decision. And while it's not strictly necessary to implement `IEnumerable<>` it certainly is a good idea (be it for Linq alone).

Comment: OK, but im having trouble grasping whats happening behind the scenes..
what exactly am i returning as an enumerator?, when i go to IEnumerator<> definition, i see "T Current { get; }" but what about next and reset?

Comment: @IdanBoadana: Maybe I'm misinterpreting what you're asking, but the `yield return` syntax was added as a convenience/sanity feature. Behind the scenes, the C# compiler is creating a basic iterator implementation _for you_ and compiling it in on the fly. For example, if you executed: `myListUserLoggedIn.GetEnumerator().GetType()` you'd find it produced some anonymously named type (maybe something like `d__0`, but with additional flavour that I can't recall off the top of my head right now)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First a smaller and simplified self-contained version:

```
class Program
{
    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()  // IEnumerable<int> works too.
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)     
            yield return i;     
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var p = new Program();

        foreach (int x in p)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
    }
}
```

And the 'strange' thing here is that `class Program` does not implement `IEnumerable`.

The specs from Ecma-334 say:

> § 8.18 Iterators
> The foreach statement is used to iterate over the elements of an enumerable collection. In order to be  enumerable, a collection shall have a parameterless GetEnumerator method that returns an enumerator.

So that's why `foreach()` works on your class. No mention of IEnumerable. But how does the GetEnumerator() produce something that implements `Current` and `MoveNext` ?  From the same section:

> An iterator is a statement block that yields an ordered sequence of values. An iterator is distinguished from a normal statement block by the presence of one or more yield statements
>
> It is important to understand that an iterator is not a kind of member, but is a means of implementing a function member

So the body of your method is an iterator-block, the compiler checks a number of constraints (the method must return an IEnumerable or IEnumerator) and then implements the `IEnumerator` members for you.

And to the deeper "why", I just learned something too. Based on an annotation by Eric Lippert in "The C# Programming Language 3rd", page 369:

> This is called the "pattern-based approach" and it dates from before generics. An interface based approach in C#1 would have been totally based on passing `object` around and value types would  always have had to be boxed. The pattern approach allows
>
> `foreach (int x in myIntCollection)`
>
> without generics and without boxing. Neat.

Comment: Wow, something new everyday. What's the a reason why `foreach` works on classes that simply _define_ a method of the correct signature and not implement `IEnumerable`? EDIT: I mean, the reasoning beyond "the specification says so". I understand that this isn't always answerable. :)

Comment: Thanks allot henk!
so if im getting the point, the yield statement creates a new Enumerable object from the type of the left side of the equation, which implements all the necessary logic?

Comment: Found an 'annotation, I'll add to my answer.

Comment: @IdanBoadana - Yes, kind-of. The `yield` statements invokes a lot of compiler magic for the surrounding block.

Comment: Regarding the annotation: hey, that's not a bad idea. I wonder if generics had existed as of C#1.0 whether or not it'd be implemented differently.

Comment: See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/06/30/following-the-pattern.aspx for additional thoughts on this.